# nginx - serve only with backend or 404, no static files in root

Tags: nginx, configuration, uwsgi, flask

I am trying to serve all requests with the backend (uwsgi for flask in this case) and if the backend has no such path, nginx should return 404.

Somehow I only can get the backend to take over when I use

```
try_files $uri @uwsgi;
```

But that way, you can access all files in the root directory. I don't want to serve all files in the root directory.

I also tried this:

```
try_files @uwsgi =404;
```

But then I get an 404 even if the path is defined in my flask app.

More context:
Ubuntu 14.04, nginx 1.4.6

```
    location @uwsgi {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:$document_root/myapp.sock;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri @uwsgi;
    }

    location /static/ {
            try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

The flask app is like this:

```
@app.route('/test')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

So when I visit example.com/test I want to have the flask backend handle this. But I don't want nginx to serve all files in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `try_files` if you never have any files you want to try and you always want to pass to your WSGI handler? Did you try simply making uwsgi_pass the root location?

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:$document_root/myapp.sock;
}
```

You can combine it with a static location/static server name that serves files out of a regular folder but only for that static URL.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, that is a solution to the problem I posted. 
Sorry I tried to make the problem as minimal as possible but got a bit confused by all the variations I tried.
So why does `try_files @uwsgi =404;` is not working?
The 404 returned by your solution is showing a different page than the `=404` page by the way. How would I go about returning another status code than 404?

Comment: When you proxy a request, nginx always returns the result just the way the proxied server returns them. So you're getting the 404 page of your flask app. If you want to use a custom 404 page (and not specify it within flask), you can use the "proxy_intercept_errors" directive and an "error_page" directive.